# In Flutter, how to solve an incompatible version of kotlin error in android release build?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, gradle

**Environment**

Flutter: 3.0.5
Kotlin: 1.7.20
kotlin-stdlib-jdk8

**Purpose**

Build Android APK File in release mode

**How do that**

This is my code to build apk file.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter build apk --release
```

**Error**

This is my error message when I implement above shell code.

```json
e: /Users//StudioProjects//build/share_plus/.transforms/2c8ad6c3ed6865483ab1ac32ee1a9863/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/share_plus_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users//StudioProjects//build/package_info_plus/.transforms/708f59239c66d31b675f8f4ee34ee1d9/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/package_info_plus_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users//StudioProjects//build/fluttertoast/.transforms/95f2e7bfbae2fc223e7bf3191b7aa623/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/fluttertoast_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users//StudioProjects//build/android_path_provider/.transforms/edfd77edce879858dafd77e25d3cb4a2/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/android_path_provider_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users//.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.7.20/eac6656981d9d7156e838467d2d8d79093b1570/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users//.gradle/caches/transforms-3/ee92fad3c15ec273078941d90aeb99b8/transformed/jetified-core-ktx-1.9.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users//.gradle/caches/transforms-3/dd1de6c8935c307af0ebf7d231a03cc8/transformed/core-1.9.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users//.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.annotation/annotation/1.5.0/857678d6b4ca7b28571ef7935c668bdb57e15027/annotation-1.5.0.jar!/META-INF/annotation.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users//.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.7.20/2a729aa8763306368e665e2b747abd1dfd29b9d5/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users//.gradle/caches/transforms-3/89f35fad650baf3e610ba5d6d0a34bc4/transformed/jetified-annotation-experimental-1.3.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/annotation-experimental_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users//.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.7.20/726594ea9ba2beb2ee113647fefa9a10f9fabe52/kotlin-stdlib-1.7.20.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: /Users//.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.7.20/e15351bdaf9fa06f009be5da7a202e4184f00ae3/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.20.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
```

**Try**

I changed Kotlin version(1.5.1 -> 1.7.20) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk(7 -> 8) version. But that was not working.

---

For time reasons, the Flutter version cannot be upgraded. Is there any other way?

Answer (score -1):

You changed more:
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
....
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).